# SQL - Deleting multiple entries

Tags: sql, sqlite, dart

I've been trying to teach myself some basic SQL to implement into an application I'm creating using database management.

Quickly after implementation, I realised that I wasn't sure how to deal with duplicate entries. Looking online it seems that I need to assign a 'Unique' constraint to each piece of data that is likely to be duplicated, but I wanted to know if I could approach this in a different way.

**In conclusion**, I've come up with a different idea in which to approach this issue, I'm not sure how to write this in SQL or even if it's a feasible idea.

**I'd like some outside input to either help me accomplish this or to disprove my idea.**

> Using the dart language I can seek all duplicate entries, and how many
>   duplicates are present. This is what I'm using to get this result:
>
> ```
> SELECT `title`, COUNT(*) FROM `Article` GROUP BY `url` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
> ```
>
> And this is the result
>
> `flutter: [{title: US Stock Market Chalks up Huge Weekly Losses; Bitcoin, DXY Impress, COUNT(*): 2}, {title: What Triggered Ethereum to Rise 66% Within 1 Week? Factors and Trends, COUNT(*): 26}, {title: What’s Next for Crypto Miners?, COUNT(*): 2}]`
>
> Could I perhaps delete all duplicate results by the amount returned by
>   `COUNT(*)` **minus one**?
>
> This would mean that if I had 26 duplicates of `What Triggered
>   Ethereum to Rise 66% Within 1 Week? Factors and Trends`, I could
>   delete the number represented by `COUNT(*)`, being 26 but before
>   deletion minus 1 from the number 26, effectively leaving me with one
>   duplicate left over? (being the desired result of using the
>   aforementioned 'Unique' constraint)

**Edit**: This is the SQL line I use to input a new row of data to my database.

```
'INSERT INTO Article(title, description, url, urltoimage, publishedat) VALUES("$title", "$description", "$url", "$urlToImage", "$publishedAt")'
```

Comment: Why do you think it's better to delete duplicates after they were created instead of preventing them to be created beforehand?

Comment: Would that be something I'd need to consider in my SQL query or application side?

Comment: Agreed with sticky bit, you should rather implement a unicity constraint on the combination of columns which define your natural key and for which you don’t want duplicates. Having a process to delete duplicates seems just troublesome to manage.

Comment: @Jake: The easy, well tested and "standard" way is a unique constraint. Let the database reject duplicates and you don't need to program any extra checks and deletes, etc.. But maybe you have a good reason why you don't want the DB to reject duplicates. Knowing such a reason might help to understand what you're trying to do. That's why I asked.

Comment: @Alexis.Rolland Please check my edit. I've included the line of code I use to input each row of data, what do I need to change?

Comment: @stickybit I'm not doing this for any special reason, the SQL package I'm using simply doesn't reject duplicates and I'm trying to get more insight into an Idea I'm having. If you believe this is a waste of time (I'm starting to think so) could you please lay out some kind of explanation of how I'd create a unique constraint for my database? Thanks

Comment: @Jake: One way to create a unique constraint when you create the table: `CREATE TABLE <table name> (<columns definitions>, UNIQUE (<unique column names>);`. `table_name` might be `article` and `<unique column names>` might be `url` in your case.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll take a look at this in a short while

Comment: Would the unique column names differ from the current column names that I've already got in place? This is the SQL I use to create my current database. `CREATE TABLE Article (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, description TEXT, url TEXT, urltoimage TEXT, publishedat TEXT)`

Comment: @stickybit Just in case you haven't seen it ^^^

Comment: @Jake: If I'm right and you don't want to have duplicate URLs that would be `CREATE TABLE Article (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, description TEXT, url TEXT, urltoimage TEXT, publishedat TEXT, UNIQUE (url));`

Comment: @stickybit I've managed to get it working. I used the same method as you with the exception of naming the `constraint` as `article_constraint`.  This is what I managed to get working. `CREATE TABLE Article (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, description TEXT, url TEXT, urltoimage TEXT, publishedat TEXT, CONSTRAINT article_constraint UNIQUE (url));`

Comment: Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could delete all bar 1 entry an a per url basis
- assuming that the url column should be unique 
- if a combination of more than just the url column or another column simply change the first two WHERE clauses.
- the assumption is also made that the table is not a WITHOUT ROWID table.

:-

```
SELECT count() FROM article WHERE url = 'myurl';
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT rowid AS thisrowid
    FROM article 
    WHERE url = 'myurl'
    ORDER by url
    LIMIT (SELECT count(*)-1  FROM article WHERE url = 'myurl')
)
DELETE FROM article WHERE rowid IN (SELECT thisrowid FROM cte);
```

This uses a CTE (Common Table Expression (temporary table)) to extract the **rowid** (a special normally hidden column that always exists unless WITHOUT ROWID is specified) from all bar 1 row of the **article** table according to the selection criteria (WHERE clause) (in this case where the url column contains myurl). That is LIMIT is used and this is the number of rows according to the same WHERE clause less 1.

This CTE, a slist of the rowids is then used as the basis for the DELETE's WHERE clause.

### Working Example SQL

The above was tested using the following SQL :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS article;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS article (title TEXT, description TEXT, url TEXT, urltoimage TEXT, publisheddat);
INSERT INTO article VALUES
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl','myimageurl','2018-01-01'),
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl','myimageurl','2018-01-01'),
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl','myimageurl','2018-01-01'),
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl','myimageurl','2018-01-01'),
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl','myimageurl','2018-01-01'),
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl','myimageurl','2018-01-01'),
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl','myimageurl','2018-01-01'),
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl','myimageurl','2018-01-01'),
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl','myimageurl','2018-01-01'),
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl','myimageurl','2018-01-01'),
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl','myimageurl','2018-01-01'),
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl','myimageurl','2018-01-01'),
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl','myimageurl','2018-01-01'),
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl','myimageurl','2018-01-01'),
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl','myimageurl','2018-01-01'),
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl','myimageurl','2018-01-01')
;
SELECT count() FROM article WHERE url = 'myurl';
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT rowid
    FROM article 
    WHERE url = 'myurl'
    ORDER by url
    LIMIT (SELECT count(*)-1  FROM article WHERE url = 'myurl')
)
-- SELECT * FROM cte;
DELETE FROM article WHERE rowid IN (SELECT * FROM cte);
SELECT count() FROM article WHERE url = 'myurl';
```

#### The Results from the two queries being :-

Number of rows before the deletion :-

[image]

number of remaining rows :-

[image]

---

## Alternative simpler and fixes issue re-occurring

Saying that it would probably be as easy to

1. create a new table e.g. article_new table including the UNIQUE constraint but otherwise identical and
2. then populate this from the existing table (using INSERT OR IGNORE to not fail when dropping the duplicates).
3. then rename the original table (could drop it but safer not to) e.g. to article_old
4. then rename the new table to the original table name
5. lastly drop the renamed (if happy to do so).

The code could be (again assuming url column needs to be unique) :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS article_new;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS article_old;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS article_new (title TEXT, description TEXT, url TEXT UNIQUE, urltoimage TEXT, publisheddat);
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO article_new SELECT * FROM article;
ALTER TABLE article RENAME TO article_old;
ALTER TABLE article_new RENAME TO article;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS article_old;
```

### Working Example (note more rows added with 3 different url columns) :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS article;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS article (title TEXT, description TEXT, url TEXT, urltoimage TEXT, publisheddat);
INSERT INTO article VALUES
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl','myimageurl','2018-01-01'),
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl','myimageurl','2018-01-01'),
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl','myimageurl','2018-01-01'),
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl','myimageurl','2018-01-01'),
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl','myimageurl','2018-01-01'),
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl','myimageurl','2018-01-01'),
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl','myimageurl','2018-01-01'),
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl','myimageurl','2018-01-01'),
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl','myimageurl','2018-01-01'),
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl','myimageurl','2018-01-01'),
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl','myimageurl','2018-01-01'),
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl','myimageurl','2018-01-01'),
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl','myimageurl','2018-01-01'),
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl','myimageurl','2018-01-01'),
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl','myimageurl','2018-01-01'),
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl','myimageurl','2018-01-01'),
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl2','myimageurl','2018-01-01'),
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl3','myimageurl','2018-01-01'),
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl3','myimageurl','2018-01-01'),
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl3','myimageurl','2018-01-01'),
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl3','myimageurl','2018-01-01'),
    ('Title001','Description001','myurl3','myimageurl','2018-01-01')
;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS article_new;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS article_old;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS article_new (title TEXT, description TEXT, url TEXT UNIQUE, urltoimage TEXT, publisheddat);
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO article_new SELECT * FROM article;
ALTER TABLE article RENAME TO article_old;
ALTER TABLE article_new RENAME TO article;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS article_old;
SELECT * FROM article;
```

#### The result :-

[image]

Comment: Hey Mike, thanks for the answer. It’s 1am in my country so I’ll check this out in the morning. Thanks

Comment: Actually ignore that one I think. Will be adding simple way.

Comment: Sure thing, speak tomorrow.

Comment: This is perfect Mike, thanks for helping me materialise my idea. It's obviously more efficient to just prevent duplicate entries from entering a database through the use of a unique constraint, in this case I used `url`, but it's nice to see other methods in action. Thanks again, wishing you a Merry Christmas/Happy new year!